# What is the best approach to having the certs inside a container in kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, azure-aks

I see that normally a new image is created, that is, a dockerfile, but is it a good practice to pass the cert through environment variables? with a batch that picks it up and places it inside the container

Another approach I see is to mount the certificate on a volume.

What would be the best approximation to have a single image for all environments?
Just like what happens with software artifacts, I mean.

Creating a new image for each environment or renewal I find it tedious, but if it has to be like this...

Comment: Using Volumes is one of the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely do **not** bake certificates into the image.

Because you tagged your question with `azure-aks`, I recommend using the Secrets Store CSI Driver to mount your certificates from Key Vault.

- See the [plugin project page on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure)
- See also this doc [Getting Certificates and Keys using Azure Key Vault Provider](https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/docs/configurations/getting-certs-and-keys/)
- This doc is better, more thorough and worth going through even if you're not using the nginx ingress controller [Enable NGINX Ingress Controller with TLS](https://azure.github.io/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/docs/configurations/ingress-tls/)

And so for different environments, you'd pull in different certificates from one or more key vaults and mount them to your cluster. Please also remember to use different credentials/identities to grab those certs.

Answer (score 1):

The cloud native approach would be to not have your application handle the certificates but to externalize that completely to a different mechanism.

You could have a look at service meshs. They mostly work with the sidecar pattern, where a sidecar container is running in the pod, that handles en-/decryption of your traffic. The iptables inside the pod are configured in a way, that all traffic must go through the sidecar.

Depending on your requirements you can check out [istio](https://istio.io/latest/) and [linkerd](https://linkerd.io/) as service mesh solutions.

If a service mesh is not an option I would recommend to store your certs as secret and mount that as volume into your container.